# Angeles National Forest Trail data

Tags: geospatial

I'm looking for data, in any geospatial format, of [hiking trails in the Angeles National Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angeles_National_Forest#Trails). The [Forest Service](https://www.fs.usda.gov/angeles)'s geospatial webpage seems to be broken.

Comment: Can you contact the GIS team at the Angeles National Forest ? There should be either phone number or email ? I checked and yes it is broken but you do need to let them know of the broken link.

Comment: what geospatial webpage is that? aka, url?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a hold of it, here is an external USFS Region 5 Geospatial Data that you can download to...

https://www.fs.usda.gov/main/r5/landmanagement/gis

Comment: have you verified the trails data is there? this chart says they don't have it, and trying to use the extraction tool does the same. http://apps.fs.fed.us/webapps/DataStatusTable/

Comment: Sometimes they update their trails. so it is hard to keep up trails since each Forest Service Supervisor Office gets them from their district offices and they do not always keep up the latest new trails. That is why I gave the link to check the Angeles National Forest. If it doesn't show up, then it's better to contact them by phone or email. I am sure one of their employees will pass it along to the GIS team.